# How to change font of all the text in an SVG image at once using inkscape?

Tags: fonts, inkscape, svg

I am using GeoGebra to render geometric figures. Really nice software but it seems the text font cannot be changed in it.

I know I can change font of text using `inkscape` by individually selecting all the text-boxes but I was wondering if there is way to change the font of all the text at once.

Comment: CTRL+A then click Text > Text and Font, select a font. Hit Apply.

Comment: It does not work. I am guessing it's a little bit different with an SVG image...

Comment: It won't work if the text has been converted to  outlines.  The text will not be editable.

Comment: @BillyKerr If possible, can you take a look at this question? [How to search and replace text in multiple lines in SVG effectively?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65939405/3416774)

Comment: @BillyKerr I have successfully applied it once, but now the apply button is gray for me

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In recent versions of Inkscape there is an extension called "Replace font" which can list all the used fonts in the document, find & replace specific fonts, or replace all the fonts in the document or current selection.

To use the tool, navigate to Extensions -> Text -> Replace Font.
[image: Inkscape List all fonts tab]

On the "List all fonts" tab, if you click "Apply", you'll be presented with a list of all fonts used:
[image: Inkscape List of all fonts dialog]

There are also tabs for "Replace font" and for "Find and Replace font".
[image: Inkscape Find and Replace font]

Note that to use these tools I believe you must copy / paste from the list of all fonts; there is no dialog. Also note that the tools can be applied to the entire drawing or just the current selection by changing the "Work on:" selection at the bottom of each tab.

Comment: A very nice feature of Inkscape. Sad that the `Find font` field does not offer the installed fonts as options. Anyway, copy-paste from `List all fonts` is not a tragedy. ;)

Comment: IMPORTANT NOTE: You **must** include the quotation marks (e.g., `'Myriad Pro'`) from the font list. Otherwise the script will say that there is no such font. (At least this is the case on Inkscape 1.2.)

Answer (score 5):

This question is a little old, but this might help others...

I noticed that inkscape changes the font sizes along with the font type, so if you want to replace the font for things even if the are different sizes, it will change all the text to one size.

I found a workaround for this though. Since SVG is just a XML document, you can open it notepad, search for the font names, and replace with the desired font names. Of course, this will be a headache if you have more than one font names that you are replacing, but maybe it is less of a headache than fixing the font sizes. I was able to do it with one of my SVGs now, and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

When exporting from Geogebra, you have to deactivate "export text as shapes":

[image]

Then you can select one Text in Inkscape (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>LeftMouseBtn</kbd> to avoid ungrouping), select all of the same kind (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) and click the text tool, to change all texts at once.

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+A is for 'select all in all layers', not 'select same'. 'Select same object type' is 'Shift+Alt+A'. See also https://inkscape.org/en/doc/keys092.html#idm1363 and the keyboard config in Inkscape's preferences.