# How can I change every instance of sans-serif to a different font in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

This question asks about bulk changing a font in Inkscape: [How to change font of all the text in an SVG image at once using inkscape?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/101877/how-to-change-font-of-all-the-text-in-an-svg-image-at-once-using-inkscape)

That works, but only on text with a font selected. Text with the default "sans-serif" font is not changed by the Replace Font extension.

Is there a way to replace all use of the sans-serif with a selected font?

Edit: I tried Billy Kerr's suggestion, but it didn't work. The font did not change. The dialogue looks messed up too.

[image]

Comment: Try the other method I mentioned in the comments for that question. Select all the text boxes whose text you wish to change, then click *Text > Text and Font*, select a font in the Text and Font panel. Hit Apply.  Note this will only work on editable text boxes, it won't work on images of text or text which has been converted to outlines. It will also change all the text in the whole text box, which may not be so useful if you have different fonts inside the one text box.

Comment: @BillyKerr Thanks, I tried but it didn't work.

Comment: Hmmm . . .  are you sure you have editable text? Also was Inkscape used to create the text originally? BTW I can't reproduce the problem with the Text dialog.

Comment: It is editable text. I created it in Inkscape using the text tool. Thanks.

Comment: That's odd because it works for me. [see example here](https://imgur.com/idhdSsV).  What version of Inkscape do you have?  The screen capture I did was using Inkscape 1.2.2 - the most recent stable version.

Comment: Also can you please edit your username to something that is actually typable otherwise I can't address you directly in the comments. Really annoying.